# Is there a way to modify URL without triggering a view replacement?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a view that handle several URLs. Depending on the Url, different tabs are displayed inside the view. For instance `/view/tab-1` should show the view with tab 1 and  `/view/tab-2` should show the view with tab 2. The view is a handled by a Controller.

```dart
routeInitializer(Router router, RouteViewFactory views) =>
    views.configure({
      'view': ngRoute(
        path: '/view',
        mount: {
          'tab-1': ngRoute(
            path: '/tab-1',
            view: 'view.html'
          ),
          'tab-2': ngRoute(
            path: '/tab-2',
            view: 'view.html'
          ),
        }
      )
  });
```

When a user switch between tabs (by clicking on them) I'd like to update de URL to reflet the selected tab. However when I use `router.gotoUrl('/view/tab-2')` a new view is injected and that lead to a blank flash. Moreover a new Controller is instantiated and several datas are fetched one more time.

Is there a way to add an URL in the browser history without triggering the view replacement ?